# How do i retrieve my contacts from google account using my computer

Tags: contacts

Hie, my phone just stopped working, and now I need to retrieve my contacts asap, how do I go about retrieving contacts

Answer (score 1):

If you added them to your google contacts you should be able to access them here: [contacts.google.com](https://contacts.google.com) hope this helps!